# How to Install Vue.js in Laravel 6.2

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am using laravel 6.2 and now i want install Vue.js.i am trying like this

1. composer require laravel/ui.
2. php artisan ui vue.
3. php artisan ui vue --auth.
4. npm install.
5. npm run dev.

but when i try to run command **php artisan ui vue** its says **Could not open input file: artisan**

Comment: `php artisan preset vue` run this  then `npm i` and `npm run dev`

Comment: not working (Could not open input file: artisan)

Comment: please run cmd in right dir `artisan` file should be present there

Comment: have you run composer install inside your new app

Comment: are you in the right file?

Comment: are you on windows or mac/linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use `php artisan` if you are not inside a laravel project folder.

That is why it says '**Could not open input file - artisan**'.

You need to be inside laravel folder & make sure that **artisan** file exist there

If you are on Linux/MAC then use `ls` command, if you are on Windows then use `dir` command to check your current directory

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `php artisan` if you are NOT inside a laravel project folder.

Just use `cd` to go to your project_directory and try again